# Can a column be swapped having that column as composite key

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table named **bill** having primary key comprised of the combination of `bill_id` and `bill_portal` column and 2 more columns `amount` and `currency`.

```
bill_id bill_portal amount  currency
100     10          33      D
100     20          43      D
```

so how can I swap `bill_portal` values to get the following result?

```
 bill_id    bill_portal amount  currency
    100     20          33      D
    100     10          43      D
```

Comment: Please describe your question properly.

Comment: (1) Tag with the database you are using. (2) What is the issue with your query?

Comment: Show what you want, the two rows after the swap. Have you tried any queries? If so, show them and any errors or messages you saw.

Comment: Sample data would be helpful. means what kind of result you want. If I understand your question correctly. You can update bill_Portal value anytime as long as it maintains uniqueness in your table.

Comment: I have tried with the below query and it ran successfully: update bill 
set bill_portal = case when bill_portal=10 then 20 else 10 end.
But  i didn't get the updated values in the table

Comment: @PraroopKhare the filtering clause is *WHERE*, not CASE. Had you run that in a production table you'd have replaced *every bil_portal value* with a 10 or 20